# in the differentiable space, whether or not they are norms, these expressions

Tags: general-topology

consider the space of continuously differentiable functions over $[a,b]$
decide whether or not expressions are norms.

1. $ máx~_ {t \in [a,b]}  | x' \ (t)|$

Solución:
no, of course because if x (t) = 1 (for example) its norm would be null, but it is not the null function.

2. $ \ ( máx ~ _{t \in [a,b]}~ | x' (t) |) + | x (a)| $

Solución:
yes it is since : $ \| x (t) \| \ge 0 $

$ \| x (t) \|= 0$ if and only if $x (t)$ is the constant null function.
$ \| \lambda * x(t) \| = | \lambda | \| x(t) \| $

$ \|x(t)+ y (t) \| \le \| x(t) \| + \| y (t) \|$
It is enough to note that the maximum of the sum is less than or equal to the sum of maximums.

b) The norms $\| ~ \|_1 and \| \|_2 $ are said equivalent, if and only if, there are real numbers, $α> 0, β> 0$  such that $ α \| \|_1≤\| \|_2≤β\| \|_1$.

Consider the relation $\| \|_1∼\| \|_2$  if and only if, $\| \|_1$ and $ \| \|_2 $ are equivalent, check that $ ∼$ is an equivalence relation.

Solución:

if it is a norm, by the reflexive properties (every norm is equivalent to itself); symmetric (if 1 is equivalent to 2, 2 is equivalent to 1); transitive (if 1 is equivalent to 2 and 2 is equivalent to 3, then 1 is equivalent to 3).

for the symmetric:

$ \alpha , \beta > 0 $

$α\| \|_1≤\| \|_2 $ then $ \| \|_1≤ \frac{1}{\alpha}~ \| \|_2 $

$\| \|_2≤β\| \|_1 $ then $ \frac{1}{\beta} \| \|_2≤\| \|_1$

then:

Then:

$αα' \| \|_1≤\| \|_3≤ββ′\| \|_1$

c) consider $(X, \| \|) $ Banach space, prove that $ (X × X, \| \|_0)$ where $ \| (x, y) \|_0 = max (\|x\|, \|y\|)$ is a Banach space.

this right ? part c) how is it demonstrated? I appreciate your help please, am studying for an exam, I would like you to help me with the demonstration.

Comment: c) is straight forward. Please show your effort in answering it. Your answers to  a) and b) are fine.

Comment: every Cauchy sequence in $ \  (X × X, \|  \|_0) $  is convergent.      if $ \ {(x_n, y_n)}$  is Cauchy on  $ \ (X × X, \|  \|_0)$, then ${x_n} $ and $ {y_n} $ are Cauchy on X. Because $X $ is complete,$   {x_n } → x$  and $  {y_n  } → y $ are convergent in $ X.$   .  then  $ \  {(x_n, y_n)} → (x, y)$  in $ (X × X, \|  \|_0) $

Comment: this right? can you help me complement it?

Comment: Your answer to $b$ only covers symmetry. Do you have proofs for reflexivity and transitivity too?

Comment: I don't have them, how would it be for this case? thanks for answering.

Comment: Concerning your answer for c, you first should show that $\|(x,y)\|_0 = \max(\|x\|, \|y\|)$ defines a norm on $X\times X$. Also, explain why $(x_n, y_n)$ being Cauchy implies both $x_n$ and $y_n$ are Cauchy. And then show that if $x_n \to x, y_n \to y$ it must be that $(x_n, y_n) \to (x,y)$ under the norm $\|\ \|_0$.

Comment: There is an obvious choice for $\alpha, \beta$ to show that a metric $\|\ \|$ is equivalent to itself. And you seem to have the end of a proof of transitivity included, but have left the start of it out. How about you give the rest of it instead of trying to be lazy?

Comment: if $ \ {(x_n, y_n)} $ is Cauchy then for all $ϵ> 0$  there exists $ N∈N$  such that for all m, n greater than N is $ ∥ (x_m − x_n, y_m − y_n) ∥0 = max {∥x_m− x_n∥, ∥$  and $ m − y_n∥} <ϵ$ . Since both $∥y_m − y_n∥ $ and $∥y_m − y_n∥ $ are less than $ max {∥x_m − x_n∥, ∥y_m − y_n∥} < $ϵ both are Cauchy sequences.

Comment: Because X is complete, how can it be shown that $ \ {x_n} → x $ and $ \ {y_n} → y $ are convergent on X.